# How to write a program on python to determine whether a value is even or odd

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python programming and one of my first questions was to write a program to determine whether a user-given number is even or odd. This is what I did;

```
num = (int(input("Enter a number")):
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        print ("Even")
    else:
        print ("Odd")
```

but when I run it, there is an error. Do you know where my mistake is?

Comment: It would help if you showed us what the error was.

Comment: this is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "None", line 1, in <module>
Syntax Error: num = (int(input("Enter a number")):: None, line 1, pos 36

Comment: You shouldn't have ":" at the end of the input line.

Comment: I removed those but this appeared:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "None", line 1, in <module>
Syntax Error: num = (int(input(Enter a number)):: None, line 1, pos 24

Comment: Are you sure? Because on that error, it looks like you've still got it there.

Comment: I guess you're right. Ok I'll keep trying then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
if not num%2:
    print("Even")
else:
    print("Odd")
```

Comment: Should probably remove the indent on the last 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input("Please Enter a Number : "));  
if(a&1==1):  
    print("This Number is Odd")    
else:  
    print("This Number is Even")
```